# Does a dense subset of a projective variety has the same dimension as the variety?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-geometry

I know that an open subset of a projective variety, which is dense, has the same Krull dimension as the projective variety and I also know that, in general, a dense subset may not have the same Krull dimension as the set. Therefore I wonder if a dense subset of a projective variety will have the same Krull dimension? Here, the projective variety is the standard closed subset of projective space under Zariski topology and Krull dimension means the supremum of lengths of chains of closed irreducible sets.

Comment: A good answer depends on your definition of a variety. Please add your definition to your post.

Comment: By variety, I mean the standard closed subset of projective space under Zariski topology, I am not sure if I should add these, because I think it is the standard meaning.

Comment: It is defined to be the supremum of lengths of chains of closed irreducible sets.

Comment: The definition of variety is important - if you take the schemey definition, then any irreducible variety has a single point which is dense (called the generic point), which resolves your question very quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$S=\{ (1/n,e^{-n}),n\ge 1\}\subset \Bbb{A^2(C)}$$
$S\cap V(f)$ is finite for any non-zero polynomial $f\in \Bbb{C}[x,y]$.

> (A parametrization of a locally irreducible analytic hypersurface passing through $(0,0)$ is of the form $(t^k,g(t))$ or $(g(t),t^k)$ with $g(0)=0$ and $g$ analytic near $0$, so it can't pass through infinitely many points of $S$)

Thus $S$ is dense in $\Bbb{A^2(C)}$.

$\Bbb{A^2(C)}$ has a chain of 3 irreducibles subsets  whereas, since $S\cap V(f)$ is finite, $S$ has a chain of only 2

$$(0,0)\subset V(x)\subset \Bbb{A^2(C)},\qquad (1/n,e^{-n})\subset S$$

Replacing $\Bbb{A^2(C)}$ by $\Bbb{P^2(C)}$ answers your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, though I do not entirely understand why the intersection is finite, I think your example works.

Comment: May I ask, are you using the identity theorem in complex analysis? Since $S$ is obviously sitting inside the graph of an analytic function and $S$ has the origin as an accumulation point, if any polynomial agree with the analytic function at infinitely many points in $S$, it will have to agree entirely but that analytic function is not a polynomial. I am not sure if this is what you mean.

Comment: In dimension $\ge 2$ it is more complicated. I think the solution is really to say that any infinite subset of S doesn't fit with a local chart of an hypersurface